# [Missing value for primary key]

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities with a manytoone relation :
Egwprestation <--  EgwAddressbook

When i manipulate entities (repository), i have this message :

**Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\OutOfBoundsException: "Missing value for primary key addressbookId on Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwAddressbook" at /htdocs/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/Exception/OutOfBoundsException.php line 40**

Here is my egwAddressbook entity:

```
<?php

namespace Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwAddressbook
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="egw_addressbook")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwAddressbookRepository")
 */
class EgwAddressbook
{
    /**
     * @var integer $addressbookId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="addressbook_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $addressbookId;

    /**
     * @var string $contactId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contact_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $contactId;
```

Here is my EgwPrestation entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EgwAddressbook", inversedBy="prestationsP")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_contact_prescripteur", referencedColumnName="contact_id")
 */
    private $contactPr;
```

SO, it's a simple ManytoOne relation between 2 entities.

Searching for a lot of days...

**Thanks for your help**

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is not correct, you can't reference to `contact_id` of EgwAddressbook since it is not a primary key. I am not really sure what do you need in term of mapping but if you want that **Many EgwPrestations have one EgwAddressbook** try this instead :

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="EgwAddressbook")
 * @JoinColumn(name="id_contact_prescripteur", referencedColumnName="addressbook_id")
 */
private $contactPr`
```

The [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html) is very useful and can help you to determine what kind of mapping fits to your needs.

Comment: Thank you but, the problem is the same : i created addressbook_id to avoid contact_id in the joincolumn. And it's the same problem.